# How do I align items in a td?

Tags: html, css

This is a part of my table. I have a button and 2 images in the td. I want to move them to the center. How do I do it? I have tried padding, margin. But they doesn't work.

```
<td align="center" style="width: 200px;">

  <input type="button" name="submit" onClick="mySubmit();"
         style="position: relative; float: left; top: 10%" value=" GO ">

  <a href="#" style="position: relative; float: left; top: 2%;" onClick="mySubmit();">
    <img src="../images/refresh.png" style="position:relative;">
  </a> 

  <input type="checkbox"  name="upsCheckbox" id="upsCheckbox" onChange="setRefresh(this.checked)"/>

  <a href="#" style="position: relative; float: left; top: 2%;" onClick="enterFullscreen();">
    <img src="../images/FullScreen.jpg" style="position: relative; top:2%;">
  </a>

</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting `text-align: center` to the `<td>` tag?

Comment: yes.. even that didn't work

Comment: have you tried `vertical-align: middle` on `<td>` tag?

Comment: @AnushaHoney its not working because you are playing with `position` property...So you need to set `top left right` and `bottom` property accordingly.

Comment: Try out <td style="text-align: center;">

Comment: @Bk Santiago didn't work

Comment: Invalid HTML markup + use of tables. This shouldn't be allowed anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VEJk7/

Simplified HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 400px;">
      <input type="button" value=" GO ">
      <a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a> 
      <input type="checkbox">
      <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

td a, td input, td img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you want horizontally center ... `text-align:center` will do the trick

**CSS::**

```
td input[name="submit"], td input[name="upsCheckbox"]{

   text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can see a new div has been added inside TD with margin auto and width..**

**HTML**

```
<td align="center" style="width: 200px">
    <div style="margin:auto;width:120px;">
              <input type="button" name="submit" onClick="mySubmit();" style="position:relative;float:left;top:10%"value=" GO ">
              <a href="#" style="position:relative;float:left;top:2%;" onClick="mySubmit();">
                    <img src="../images/refresh.png" style="position:relative;">
              </a> 
              <input type="checkbox"  name="upsCheckbox" id="upsCheckbox" onChange="setRefresh(this.checked)"/>
              <a href="#" style="position: relative;float:left;top:2%;" onClick=" enterFullscreen();">
                  <img src="../images/FullScreen.jpg" style="position: relative;top:2%;">
              </a>
   </div>
</td>
```

**Outcome**

[image]

Comment: Could you add more details?  Seems to be vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be I hadn't understand your question exactly, but I edited your code like following:

```
<table>
<td align="center" style="background-color: green; width: 200px;" >
    <input type="button" name="submit" onClick="mySubmit();" value="GO " />
    <a href="#" onClick="mySubmit();">
         <img src="../images/refresh.png" />
    </a> 
    <a href="#" onClick="enterFullscreen();" >
        <img src="../images/FullScreen.jpg" />
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="upsCheckbox" id="upsCheckbox" onChange="setRefresh(this.checked)"/>
 </td>
</table>
```

here is fiddle : (http://jsfiddle.net/bf26T/)

Comment: I have removed style attributes, added slash end of tags'.